# c# shared memory between managed and unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible on windows for unmanaged code (c++ / c) to write to an area in memory that is then accessed by managed .Net code (c#) (separate processes) I have a c program that is writing data to an circular memory buffer and I want to process the buffer with unmanaged code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution where an unmanaged process and managed process can share memory, then you can use the [MemoryMappedFile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) (introduced in .NET 4.0).

If you're looking to share memory between unmaanged and managed code in the *same* process, then you can use `GCHandle` to pin a managed array in memory, and pass it to unmanaged code which can access it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at the [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

you should use the Marshall class, especially [Marshal.AllocHGlobal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx).